# Accidentally installed MAAS Debian packages alongside MAAS snap

Tags: apt, package-management, dpkg, maas

Not able to install or uninstall packages due to the following error:

```
Preparing to unpack .../maas-common_1%3a3.0.0-10029-g.986ea3e45-0ubuntu1~20.04.1_all.deb ...
ERROR: The MAAS Debian packages may not be installed alongside the MAAS Snap!
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/maas-common_1%3a3.0.0-10029-g.986ea3e45-0ubuntu1~20.04.1_all.deb (--unpack):
 new maas-common package pre-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/maas-common_1%3a3.0.0-10029-g.986ea3e45-0ubuntu1~20.04.1_all.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Comment: Can you [edit] your question to include the version of Ubuntu you’re running?

Comment: @matigo The command output says `ubuntu1~20.04.1` so I'd guess 20.04.1

Answer (score 1):

You have to remove the mentioned MAAS deb-package by

```
sudo apt-get purge maas-common
sudo dpkg --force-all maas-common
sudo apt-get install -f
```

and then use snap instead.

Answer (score 0):

Your error seems to be self explanatory.  You need to use `$ sudo snap install   "package name"` instead of using a deb package installation method.  I also found some documentation on MAAS which may be useful. https://maas.io/docs